# Reflection and angle of refraction

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, refraction

Does the angle of refraction depend on the properties of the material if the angle of the incidence is the same for two different materials?

Say I shed light on a surface with angle $ \theta $ and shed another light with the same angle $ \theta $ on two separate surfaces, are both the refraction angle going to be the same for both?

Comment: __Refraction__ : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253794/refraction-of-light-rays/254205#254205  __Reflection__ :  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254773/reflection-of-light-rays/254796#254796

Answer (score 1):

The refraction angle will be different for different materials provided these materials have a different index of refraction. Reversely, by measuring the angle you can determine the index of refraction of the material. You can look up Snell's law.